# <Files "*.html"> does not match directory index?

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I have this in my site's conf file:

```
<Files "*.html">
    RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R]
</Files>
```

The intent is that viewing any physical .html file should require HTTPS. For application related reasons it must be a physical file; there are some URLs that contain .html that rewrite to application URLs that do not require HTTPS. For this reason I am using `<Files>` rather than a direct RewriteRule based on the URL. Basically, I need to check against the physical filename rather than the URL.

This works if the user visits `example.com/index.html` or `example.com/something/index.html` but does not work if the user visits `example.com/` or `example.com/something/` even though in both cases it is the same index.hml file that actually is displayed.

Based on the [documentation](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#files) for `<Files>` shouldn't this be matching based on the physical filename rather than the URL? Or is there some option to specify this? Or is there some other way I can make an equivalent redirect based on the physical filename?